# Dynamic form inputs not validating with Angular validation

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a form and some of the input fields are dynamically filled with an external script I have no access to. The fields are filled but when I go to submit, it thinks they are empty.

Is there a way to do this without adding an external library?

I have scope.$watch but I may be doing it wrong. Attached is the code.

EDIT: The jQuery I have in the code is just for adding the input values to mimic an external script. The user would click a button that would auto populate the input fields. I would not be able to use jQuery in my actual code, this needs to be 100% angular with jqlite.

```js
// create angular app
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.userForm = {};
  
  // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred   
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
      alert('our form is amazing');
    }
  };
});

//create directive
validationApp.directive('mainDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, el, attrs) {
    
    scope.$watch('userForm.'+attrs.name+'.$valid', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("newVal: ", newVal);
    }, true);     
 }
});

//Dynamically adding a value to the input DO NOT CHANGE
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.form .name').val('John Doe'); 
    $('.form .username').val('johnd2017'); 
    $('.form .email').val('johnd2017@test.com'); 
  }, 2000); 
});
```

```css
body { padding-top:30px; }
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">  
   
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- FORM ============ -->
  
    <form name="userForm" class="form" ng-submit="submitForm()" main-directive novalidate>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.$submitted }">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control name" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">You're name is required.</p>
        </div>
      
        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && userForm.$submitted }">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control username" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
          <p ng-show="userForm.username.$invalid && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">You're username is required.</p>
        </div>
        
        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.$submitted }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control email" ng-model="user.email" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
          <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">You're email is required.</p>
        </div>
      
      <!-- CITY -->
        <div class="form-group city">
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control city" ng-model="user.city">
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- VALIDATION TABLES ======== -->    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Form</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$valid, danger: userForm.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$pristine, danger: !userForm.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Name</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$valid, danger: userForm.name.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$pristine, danger: !userForm.name.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Username</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$valid, danger: userForm.username.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$pristine, danger: !userForm.username.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Email</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$valid, danger: userForm.email.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$pristine, danger: !userForm.email.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>City</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.city.$valid, danger: userForm.city.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.city.$pristine, danger: !userForm.city.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.city.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.city.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to avoid the use of jquery, instead use jqlite embed on angular.

Comment: the jQuery is only there to dynamically add values to the inputs for testing purposes. I am pulling in an external script that populates the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Because if some html dynamically added **after** angular compilation and linking you need to compile added part by you self using this [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

But if you only want to change value of input outside of angular, then you need to trigger input and change events on those inputs to notify angular about that change.
For example it can be done with similar code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var notifyAngularAboutChange = function () {
    $('.form .name').trigger('input');
    $('.form .name').trigger('change'); 

    $('.form .username').trigger('input'); 
    $('.form .username').trigger('change'); 

    $('.form .email').trigger('input'); 
    $('.form .email').trigger('change'); 
  };

  var checkChange = function () {
    // check for expected changes in needed elements
    // and return true if change found
  };

  vat waitForChange = function () {
    if (checkChange()) {
      notifyAngularAboutChange();
    } else {
      setTimeout(waitForChange, 100);
    }
  };

  waitForChange();
});
```